# Extract everything between quotes excluding the semicolon separator

Tags: c#, regex

i'm looking for a regex that will extract everything between quotes mark excluding the semicolon separator.

Expected result

```
azerty
y9uiuih
qwsdf
ftyg hjhh
w__g_-91
```

from

```
-from:"azerty;y9uiuih;qwsdf"
-to:"ftyg hjhh;w__g_-91"
```

What I tried `(?![[:alnum:]]+:)([[:alnum:]]+| |-|_)+`

Rules :

- they could be between 0 and an unlimited number of `;` between the quotes, each one will be a separator between two words
- There is only one pair of `"` per line
- a word between quotes can be formed with any characters excepts `;` and `"`

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: Where are you using this? If during regular programming, much easier and optimal would be to just capture between `""` and then split the string based on `;`

Comment: You could use lookarounds `(?<=""[^""\r\n]*)[^;\r\n""]+(?=[^""\r\n]*"")`  https://regex101.com/r/8oVfYV/1 See https://ideone.com/h8UFV1

Comment: Destroy666 I first implemented it with regular programming but I was wondering what is the regex for this pattern and which method will be the fastest between the the regex and programing one.
Thefourthbird it works perfectly well ! thank you very much. Don't hesitate to make an answer to this question for me to validate it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want matches only in C#, you can make use of a lookahead and a lookbehind:

```
(?<=""[^""\r\n]*)[^;\r\n""]+(?=[^""\r\n]*"")
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=""[^""\r\n]*)` Assert `"` to the left matching optional chars other than `"` or newlines in between
- `[^;\r\n""]+` Match 1+ chars other than `;` and `"` or a newline
- `(?=[^""\r\n]*"")` Assert `"` to the right matching optional chars other than `"` or newlines in between

[.NET Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8oVfYV/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/h8UFV1)

C# example:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=""[^""\r\n]*)[^;\r\n""]+(?=[^""\r\n]*"")";
string input = @"-from:""azerty;y9uiuih;qwsdf""
-to:""ftyg hjhh;w__g_-91""";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Output

```
azerty
y9uiuih
qwsdf
ftyg hjhh
w__g_-91
```

---

If the match should start with at least a word character (not matching only spaces for example) and allow the characters from the example:

```
(?<=""[^""\r\n]*)[\p{Zs}\t]*\w[\w\p{Zs}\t-]*(?=[^""\r\n]*"")
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pOt4NH/1)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see from the example output, you want

1. `Match` "words"
2. In each "word" change `;` into a new line.

Code:

```
string text = "-from:\"azerty;y9uiuih;qwsdf\"\r\n- to:\"ftyg hjhh;w__g_-91\"";

Regex regex = new Regex("\"[^\"]*\"");

string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, regex
  .Matches(text)
  .Select(match => match.Value.Trim('"').Replace(";", Environment.NewLine)));

Console.Write(result);
```

If instead of chnaging `;` into a new line you want to `Split`:

```
string text = "-from:\"azerty;y9uiuih;qwsdf\"\r\n- to:\"ftyg hjhh;w__g_-91\"";

Regex regex = new Regex("\"[^\"]*\"");

string[] words = regex
  .Matches(text)
  .SelectMany(match => match.Value.Trim('"').Split(';'))
  .ToArray();

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words));
```

Answer (score 1):

`(?<title>\w+):"((?<word>[^;"]+);?)+(?="$)`

This pattern captures the title ("from"/"to") as well as the words with named groups.

Given:

```cs
var input = """
    -from:"azerty;y9uiuih;qwsdf"
    -to:"ftyg hjhh;w__g_-91"
    """;
var pattern = """(?<title>\w+):"((?<word>[^;"]+);?)+(?="$)""";
```

We can write:

```cs
Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);       

var matches = r.Matches(input);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    string title =  m.Groups["title"].Value;
    foreach(Capture c in m.Groups["word"].Captures)
    {
        string word = c.Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"{title}: {word}");
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
from: azerty
from: y9uiuih
from: qwsdf
to: ftyg hjhh
to: w__g_-91
```

Note that the `Captures` return the repetitions of a group. In this case the words captured between the quotes.

Explanation:

- `(?<name>pattern)` captures a pattern into a named group.
- `\w+` the title is made up of at least one word character.
- `(?<title>\w+):` title followed by a semicolon.
- `[^;"]+` the words are made up of at least one character not being a semicolon or a double quote.
- `((?<word>[^;"]+);?)+` the words may be followed by an optional semicolon (`;?`) and are repeated at least once (`+`).
- `pattern(?=postfix)` the pattern must be followed by a postfix.
- `"$` the postfix is a double quote followed by a line ending. Note that we must specify the regex option `Multiline` to have `^` and `$` denote the beginning and ending of lines rather the beginning and ending of the whole string.